# Using Magic Keyboard + Mouse with 2 MacBook Pros (MacOS Catalina)

Tags: mac, keyboard, bluetooth, mouse, magic-trackpad

I have two MacBook Pros running MacOS Catalina. On my desk, I have an external monitor and a Magic Keyboard & Mouse. I'd like to easily switch the keyboard & mouse between the two laptops when I connect them to the external display. Right now, I have to re-pair the keyboard and mouse everytime I want to switch. Is there a way to automatically have the keyboard/mouse pair to whichever computer is awake and running?

Comment: This can be done with applescript, first detect when the computer wakes up and then connect to bluetooth device. You'll find examples for both here and in superuser. 
Another solution would be using third party like barrier(on GitHub) that will allow you to share a mouse and a keyboard between your MacBooks, this means that the mouse and keyboard will always be connected to one macbook (for barrier, they need to be on the same network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I found AirBuddy (https://v2.airbuddy.app/) which has this exact functionality.

Comment: Please add some details which show *how* the application helps to solve the problem.